# How to detect a Triangle gesture with kinect?

Tags: algorithm, kinect, gesture, kinect-sdk

I am trying to implement a gesture recognition system which interprets the geometric gestures user makes and draws it on screen,

I have some idea of how circle can be recognized, however I have no clue how to get started with triangle recognition.

The data I have is X and Y coordinates of all points the gesture passed through. I get this data by tracking right hand.

I found something online called Hough Transform, which is used for detecting lines but I am not sure whether it will work for discrete collections of points.

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an x,y pair for the hand, the simplest thing that comes to mind is try the [$1 Unistroke Recognizer](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/).

[image: $1 Unistroke Recognizer]

A handy thing to look at is [Dynamic Time Warping(DTW)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping).
I've seen a fun Processing/SimpleOpenNI project that makes
use of that technique and the full skeleton called [KineticSpace](http://code.google.com/p/kineticspace/).
Since it's open-source might be worth having a peak.

I'd recommend trying the $1 Unistroke Recognizer first. You probably
need to work out a system to mimic press/release (perhaps using 
the sign of the hand's velocity on z (positive to negative transitions/
negative to positive transitions) ?).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can look for a space filling curve. It reduces the 2 dimension and reorder the points. It also add some spatial information. Maybe you can train or compare the new reordered 1d index with some simulated annealing or ant colony optimization?! A space filling curve is used in map tiling programs.

Comment: did not understand most of that , but will google that and will figure out. thanks for the direction. :)

Comment: Genetic algorithms are almost never the answer ;-)

Comment: @Rook: So you deny survival of the fittest? What about simulated annealing or ant colony optimization?

Comment: "deny"? That wasn't actually what I said, was it?

Comment: @Rook: Yes, it's a double negation. I don't like it either and I updated my answer.